# Is the term "disillusion" being used correctly here?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> It's easy to disillusion ourselves by thinking just because the output of our function looks very random, that it is very random.

I asked a friend about [this passage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14869745/146406).  I argue that it should read:

> It's easy to **trick ourselves into thinking that** just because the output of our function looks very random, that it is very random."

[Miriam Webster defines disillusion](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disillusion) thus: "*to cause (someone) to stop believing that something is good, valuable, true, etc.*"

Please help us settle the dispute: **is "disillusion" being used properly here?**

Comment: ***Disillusion*** is simply *the wrong word*. You want ***delude***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, **delude** looks like a better choice, thank you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "...delude ourselves by thinking..." or "...delude ourselves *into* thinking..."?

Comment: That depends on the precise emphasis you want to convey - does that particular "thinking" lead to us being deluded *(**by**)*, or are we already engaging in the act of deluding ourselves *(**into**)*, one consequence of which is that we end up thinking those thoughts?

Comment: The latter.  The apparent randomness causes one to delude one's self into thinking that the there is genuine randomness.  TBH I think saying "trick ourselves into thinking" improves clarity 10 fold & I think the best answer is "use that."  Will wait for answers tho.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. The word is 'deceive' ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to disillusion *ourselves* just as it is not possible to administer CPR to ourselves. But we can become disillusioned, i.e. have our illusions taken away.

Comment: I think I once managed to disillusion myself. I had thought "Mihaly" was Hungarian for "Michael". I had also thought "Miklos" was Hungarian for "Michael". I held these two beliefs for quite a while before they surfaced simultaneously in my consciousness and I realized that it was quite unlikely that they were both correct. That realization seems like disillusionment to me. (It turns out that "Miklos" is "Nicholas", not Michael".)

Comment: @AndreasBlass, az érdekesseb az, hogy a _Máté_ és a _Mátyás_ egyaránt fordítható _Matthew_-ra. Jó, hogy a _Mátyás_ általánosabb fordítása _Matthias_, de manapság senki se használja a _Matthias_ nevet, míg a _Matthew_ (vagy _Mathew_) még mindig az egyik leggyakoribb név.

Comment: @Marthaª I'm afraid my knowledge of Hungarian doesn't extend much beyond "Mihaly", "Miklos", and "Magyar Posta" (I collected stamps as a child).

Comment: @Andreas Blass. You're deluded, if you think you disillusioned yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the word 'disillusion' can be used as a verb, adjective or noun.

Comment: The part of speech is only a (small) part of the question, though: clearly, there's nothing grammatically wrong with the sentence, but does it make sense? Does it mean what the writer intends it to mean?

Comment: @Martha Perhaps 'become disillusioned' would have been better in the context? So the sentence would read: 'It is easy to become disillusioned by thinking...'.